# I cannot see my sidebar widget loading on my website even though I set it up from widgets section WordPress

Tags: wordpress, widget, sidebar

My website is https://www.liquidocelot.com I setup my sidebar widget with "Latest Posts" and later I intend to add ad code from my google adsense however I cannot see it live displaying on my website please help me out with this help.

I tried flushing cache but nothing works and even checked if widget were inactive or not it seems it was active help